# scala method implicit convertion not working

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have a Play 2.3 project with custom headers coming from AJAX that need to be passed to every service call (to be passed further to the web services). I thought about making it an implicit parameter, like in this dumbed down example :

```
case class CriteriaHeaders(license: String)
case class Criteria(criteriaHeaders: CriteriaHeaders, id: Int)

class ProjectController(service: Service)  {
  implicit def criteriaToCiteriaHeaders(criteria: Criteria): CriteriaHeaders = criteria.criteriaHeaders
  def findName(criteria: Criteria) = {
    // implicit val criteriaHeaders: CriteriaHeaders = criteria.criteriaHeaders
    service
      .findName(criteria.id)
      .fold(
        error => error,
        name => name
      )
  }
}

class Service {
  def findName(id: Int)
              (implicit criteriaHeaders: CriteriaHeaders): Either[String, String] = ??? // TODO
}
```

(Of course in the real project there is an ActionBuilder, a Json parser etc.)

Usage :

```
val controller = new ProjectController(new Service())
val name = controller.findName(Criteria(CriteriaHeaders("abc"), 123))
```

It doesn't compile, giving an error :

```
Error:(21, 17) could not find implicit value for parameter licenseHeaders: A$A172.this.CriteriaHeaders.findName(criteria.id)
```

However, if I uncomment the implicit val, it works. Why it doesn't work with the implicit method?

EDIT :
In case anyone find this useful, I took second suggestion from @till-rohrmann and I put the implicit in the companion object of the CriteriaHeaders, so it is available in every controller using it.

```
object CriteriaHeaders {
  implicit def criteriaToCiteriaHeaders(implicit criteria: Criteria) = criteria.criteriaHeaders
}
```

Comment: does this work for you: `implicit def criteriaToCiteriaHeaders: CriteriaHeaders = criteria.criteriaHeaders` instead of the `val`?

Comment: Nope... I tried like this as well :
    implicit def criteriaToCiteriaHeaders: Criteria => CriteriaHeaders = implicit criteria => criteria.criteriaHeaders

but to no avail. Thanks for suggestion,  Till Rohrmann's worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that an implicit conversion which takes an explicit parameter won't be called to obtain the implicit argument for the `Service.findName` method. There are two solutions to your problem.

1. Call the `findName` method with an explicit second parameter list and the `Criteria` argument. Then the compiler knows that it has to convert the `criteria` value into a `CriteriaHeaders`.

```scala
class ProjectController(service: Service)  {
  implicit def criteriaToCriteriaHeaders(criteria: Criteria): CriteriaHeaders = criteria.criteriaHeaders
  def findName(criteria: Criteria) = {
    service
      .findName(criteria.id)(criteria)
      .fold(
        error => error,
        name => name
      )
  }
}
```

2. Make the parameter `criteria` of `ProjectController.criteriaToCriteriaHeaders` and `ProjectController.findName` implicit. Then the implicit conversion will be used.

```scala
class ProjectController(service: Service)  {
  implicit def criteriaToCiteriaHeaders(implicit criteria: Criteria): CriteriaHeaders = criteria.criteriaHeaders
  def findName(implicit criteria: Criteria) = {
    service
      .findName(criteria.id)
      .fold(
         error => error,
         name => name
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: @KaC, glad that I could help :-)